# How to use react-native-qrcode-svg for react-native-web?

Tags: react-native, svg, react-native-web

i want to use the package react-native-qrcode-svg for my react native web project, but hit this error:

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-qrcode-svg/src/index.js 29:4

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (29:4)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|
|   return (

> ```
> <G x={logoPosition} y={logoPosition}>
> ```

|       
|

I tried installing the react-native-svg-web and managed to used .svg file only, it didn't work for this package.